# Is this question a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I asked a question last night about [improvising vocals in chiptune](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/81800/how-to-improvise-vocals-in-chiptune), and then one hour later, someone else posted a question about generally [improvising vocals](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/81804/how-do-you-improvise-vocal-tunes).

Is the question about generally improvising vocals a duplicate? If not, how come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your chiptune vocals question looks like it is focusing on the chiptune side of things, whereas the other post is focusing on the improvisation side. So I would not regard them as duplicates in their current form.